Worst Case Solution for directed Chinese Postman Problem
The Problem
Let $G$ be a directed graph with $n$ vertices. How long is a shortest circuit that visits every edge in the worst case? That is how long is the solution to the directed Chinese Postman Problem (dCPP) at most?
In my specific case I know a bit more about the graph: Each vertex has the same out-degree $d$ and it is strongly connected.
Some thoughts
The idea for the most common algorithm for the dCPP goes as follows:

For each vertex $v$ calculate the imbalance $\delta(v) = \delta^+(v) - \delta^-(v)$ where $\delta^+(v)^+$ is the out-degree and $\delta^-(v)$ is the in-degree of $v$.
Duplicate shortest paths from vertices with negative imbalance to vertices with positive imbalance to make the graph Eulerian.
Compute a Eulerian path for the resulting graph

The number of paths that has to be duplicated is the sum of all positive imbalances $k = \sum_{v \in D^+} \delta(v)$ where $D^+$ is the set of all vertices with positive imbalance.
For my assumptions on the graph this leads to a bound of $(d - 1)(n - 1)$ for the number of paths $k$ (note that each vertex must have at least one in-coming edge because the graph is strongly connected, to get the bound, all other edges lead to one single vertex). Each duplicated path trivially has length at most $n - 1$. So the resulting circuit that visits every edge is at most of length $nd + (d - 1)(n - 1)^2$.
How can I improve this bound? I think especially the length of the duplicated paths can be decreased right? Any ideas?

No, you cannot really do better, as you can see in this counterexample  that is inspired by Figure 3 in your reference.
Explanation: Start with complete graph $K_{d+1}$. Delete one edge from $K_{d+1}$ and point it towards a new node $a_1$. Node $a_1$ has one edge towards $a_2$, and the rest point back towards $K_{d+1}$. The same for $a_3,a_4,\ldots, a_{\frac{n}{3}}$. Now make a `complete' graph (just strongly connected, and every outdegree is $\frac{d}{2}$ within the graph), call it $K_{n-\frac{n}{3}-d}$. Give $a_{\frac{n}{3}}$ an edge towards $K_{n-\frac{n}{3}-d}$, and give every node in $K_{n-\frac{n}{3}-d}$ exactly $\frac{d}{2}$ edges towards $K_{d+1}$. Now we look at how many edges we need for the CPP. There are $\Theta (nd)$ edges from $K_{n-\frac{n}{3}-d}$ towards $K_{d+1}$. Every time we cross one of these edges, the only way to reach another one is to go past $a_1,a_2,\ldots$, so we need $\Theta(n)$ steps to reach another, so we need $\Theta(n^2d)$ steps at the minimum, which mathches your upper bound.

Thanks for your answer :). I see now that indeed for the asymptotic case it's not possible to do better. Do you have any ideas on how to tackle the non-asymptotic case?

Not really. Obviously you are not very likely to encounter a graph like this in practice, so there might be tricks that work well for the `average' graph.
